# SQL DISTINCT Query, get unique colors from table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table that has 4 column each one has a color in HEX value (see capture below)

```
color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 |

#a0a0a0 | #f0f0f0 | #404040 | #e0e0e0 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f0 | #c0c0c0 | #e06080 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f1 | #c0c0c0 | #e06082 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f0 | #c0c0c0 | #e06080 |
```

I would like to query the whole table to get the unique colors saved, I did as following

```
SELECT DISTINCT color_1, color_2, color_3, color_4
FROM `wp_images`
```

The result I get is not what I expect (see capture below)

```
color_1 | color_2 | color_3 | color_4 |

#a0a0a0 | #f0f0f0 | #404040 | #e0e0e0 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f0 | #c0c0c0 | #e06080 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f1 | #c0c0c0 | #e06082 |
#e0e0e0 | #f0f0f0 | #c0c0c0 | #e06080 |
```

what I expect as result is :

```
#a0a0a0 , #f0f0f0 , #404040 , #e0e0e0 , #f0f0f1 , #c0c0c0 , #e06080 , #e06082
```

Any help please?

Thanks

Comment: normalization anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT color
FROM
(
SELECT color_1 as color FROM `wp_images`
UNION
SELECT color_2 as color FROM `wp_images`
UNION
SELECT color_3 as color FROM `wp_images`
UNION
SELECT color_4 as color FROM `wp_images`
)
```

The inside `SELECT`s get the list of each column from the table (`color_1`,`color_2`,`color_3`,`color_4`) and unite them under a unique table, with one column called `color`. This table is then queried, having all the colors from the 4 columns, appling `DISTINCT` to them.

Comment: Any explanation can increase the chances for upvotes,also distinct in your query is not necessary

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid - Redundant maybe, but not useless.  Useless implies that it fails to meet it's intended purpose.  In this case it's simply not necessary, but doesn't cause anything to fail in any regard.

Comment: Thank you this works  : UNION
SELECT color_2 AS color
FROM `wp_images`
UNION
SELECT color_3 AS color
FROM `wp_images`
UNION
SELECT color_4 AS color
FROM `wp_images`

Comment: @user3593154 - Please vote for any and all answers that helped you, and accept the answer that helped you most.

Answer (score 3):

Using `UNION` will enable you to combine different results.  It also natively removes duplicates from the results.

```
SELECT color1 FROM wp_images
UNION
SELECT color2 FROM wp_images
UNION
SELECT color3 FROM wp_images
UNION
SELECT color4 FROM wp_images
```

I actually prefer to put `GROUP BY color(n)` at the end of each query, or use `SELECT DISTINCT`.  It makes the behaviour clearer, but really it's not necessary.

Better still, use a different table structure.

```
 item_num | color_num | color
----------+-----------+-------
     1    |      1    | <#a0a0a0>
     1    |      2    | <#f0f0f0>
     1    |      3    | <#404040>
     1    |      4    | <#e0e0e0>
     2    |      1    | <#e0e0e0>
     2    |      2    | <#f0f0f0>
     2    |      3    | <#c0c0c0>
     2    |      4    | <#e06080>
```